# Post pictures using mobile

Tags: support, user-interface, images, ios-app

How to post pictures on mobile?  I wanted to answer a question with a diagram on my mobile.  How should I do that?

I am currently on iPhone, using the stack exchange application.

Comment: I retagged as "support". If it turns out that it's impossible, then we can make it a feature-request. Until then it is a support question.

Comment: I’m browsing Meta on mobile right now. Across the top of the answer field, there’s a grey bar that says “Add picture”. I haven’t tried it, but do you have such a thing? EDIT: [Uploaded on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6PDb.png)

Comment: No... I don’t ...

Comment: The tag "mobile-web" suggests that the Question is about using a browser on a mobile phone (or perhaps on a tablet).  Functionality of the StackExchange mobile "app" may differ.

Comment: @pjs36 I think we need to use safari to post photos

Comment: Could you clarify if you are using a stackexchange app (if so which one, Android or iPhone) or are using a browser on a mobile device. // @hardmath Good point. I removed the tag (which I had added).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you're on browser there should be something right there. If you're using the app then I'm not sure. But just switch to browser.

Comment: I'd put something in front of the image, to explain to Readers what they are about to see (presumably a screenshot of Safari browsing the StackExchange Add Answer "dialog").  As it stands your few words at the bottom are easy to miss and don't explicitly describe the image or its relevance.